# attempt to index global 'native' (a nil value)

Tags: android, ios, mobile, lua, coronasdk

I'm trying to create a textbox with this code,

```
local defaultBox

local function textListener( event )

    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
        -- User begins editing "defaultBox"

    elseif ( event.phase == "ended" or event.phase == "submitted" ) then
        -- Output resulting text from "defaultBox"
        print( event.target.text )

    elseif ( event.phase == "editing" ) then
        print( event.newCharacters )
        print( event.oldText )
        print( event.startPosition )
        print( event.text )
    end
end

-- Create text box

defaultBox = native.newTextBox( 200, 200, 280, 140 )
defaultBox.text = "This is line 1.\nAnd this is line2"
defaultBox.isEditable = true
defaultBox:addEventListener( "userInput", textListener )
```

but it's not working and telling me this:

```
attempt to index global 'native' (a nil value)
```

Comment: It's very obvious that `native` holds `nil` - not exactly a tricky error message. Is `native` supposed to be provided by the host environment, or should you be requiring it when you need it (`local native = require 'native'`), like with the `physics` library, and others, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best answer here is to break down the error.

'attempt to index' means you're treating something like a table, and trying to access a value from it.  Example:

```
t.x
t:x
t[x]
```

global native is the value you're trying to index.  The 'global' part tells you it's not a local variable, and the 'native' part is the actual name of the variable.

Since 'native' is undefined (nil), check your spelling and if you need to require it

```
local native = require 'native'
```